# x86 and x64 stack frames

Tags: c++, x86, 64-bit

What is the difference when the compiler allocates variables on the stack in x86 v x64 architectures? Say I have a function

```
foo(){
    int i = 5;
    i += 4;
}
```

how is this allocated on the stack differently in these two architectures?

Comment: Why do you want to know. Are you trying to achieve something specific or this just for informational purposes.

Comment: yeah who cares why he wants to know. sometimes you just want to know for the sake of it, and bravo to that.

Answer (score 4):

For Microsoft's x64 ABI, have a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7kcdt6fy.aspx under "Stack Usage". It is considerably different from their x86 ABI.

Other x64 ABIs (Linux, OS X, etc) are probably similar but subtly different from Microsoft's. GCC's documentation would probably be a good place to start looking for those.

Answer (score 2):

As Paul notes, the compiler probably won't put this variable on the stack at all. I just wanted to mention that the idea of the compiler running out of registers and finally using the stack for variable storage is called "register spilling", and [you can read more about it on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Register_spilling).

Answer (score 1):

The compiler is much less likely to even put this variable on the stack at all - it will most likely keep this variable in a register. The differences are on whether the compiler has to store info on the stack, moreso than *how* it stores it.

Comment: in fairnss i suspect the comiler wil completely optimise that out due to it not doing anything...

Comment: But that doesn't change between 64-bit and 32-bit compilers.  The example in the question is just that, an example.  I would assume that `i` is something that will be used a few times down the line and won't be compiled away.